# Accordion not consistently collapsing/expanding

Tags: javascript, css, accordion, liquid

Ok all, I have a dynamically rendered list that gets fed arguments from a Liquid shortcode. The accordion is not acting as it should, only every other item collapses/expands, the rest just sit there. Can't really use a `<data-target>` since it's just one dynamic block. No console errors. Here's an example of the shortcode that passes `args`:

> [regulations_accordion state="Alaska", name="Alaska is awesome",
> phone="555.222.1333", email="email@alaska.gov",
> website="http://www.blahblahblah.com/",
> regulations="https://www.googleityourself.com/"
> ][/regulations_accordion]

And the rest:

```
<ul>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">{{Args.state}}</button>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            <b>Oil and Natural Gas Representatives:</b><br>
            {{Args.name}}<br>
            Phone: {{Args.phone}}<br>
            Email: <a class="link-primary" href='mailto:{{Args.email}}'>{{Args.email}}</a><br>
            Web Site: <a class="link-primary" href='{{Args.website}}'>{{Args.website}}</a><br>
        <p>
            <b>Regulations:</b><br>
            View <a class="link-info" href="{{Args.regulations}}" target="_blank">View {{Args.state}} Regulations</a>
    </div>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
<style>
    .collapsible {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: -50px;
    }


        /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
        .active, .collapsible:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }


        .collapsible:after {
            content: '\002B';
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            float: right;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }


    .active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }


    /* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
    .content {
        padding: 0 18px;
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
</style>
```

JS Scripts

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Formatting was wonky because you posted code in the middle of a list structure (`-`). You'll want to avoid adding random characters until you get a feel for what markdown looks like.

Comment: We might need to see the rendered HTML. Maybe put that and your JS and CSS into a working snippet at the end of the post.

Comment: May be unrelated, but what on earth is `i(plusplus)` in your for loop ?

Comment: Thank you, all-mighty gatekeepers.